# Como validar valor inserido em campo de texto com php?

Tags: php, html

Tenho um projeto, que consiste em puxar um código inserido pelo usuario no seguinte campo

```
<input type=text name=CODNOME><br>
```

ele colocando os seguinte valor 001 apareça uma msg

```
<?php $CODNOME = '001' echo " testetes"; ?>
```

sei que estou perdido na lógica alguém poderia me orientar o que devo fazer ou onde procurar?

Comment: Essa mensagem vai aparecer onde? O formulário é redirecionado quando o usuário digita o código? Dê mais detalhes, se possível.

Comment: Valter o usuario permaneceria na pagina apenas com um refresh para validar e trazer a mensagem correspondente ao código inserido exemplo 

se o usuario digitar (001) vai aparecer a mensagem " A " 
se ele digitar (002) vai aparecer a mensagem " B "   

essa seria a logica que estou tentando usar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples:

```
<?php 

if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "001"){
  $msg = "mensagem1";
} 

else if(($_POST['CODNOME'] == "002"){
  $msg = "mensagem2";
}

else {
  $msg = "Opção inválida";
}

echo $msg;
?>
```

Você também pode usar o `switch`:

```
<?php 

switch($_POST['CODNOME']){
  case "001"
  $msg = "mensagem1";
  break;

  case "002"
  $msg = "mensagem2";
  break;

  default:
  $msg = "Opção inválida";
  break;
} 
echo $msg;
?>
```

Comment: Andrei Coelho estou enfrentando um dificuldade  abaixo o condigo do CODNOME, esta certa pois quando faço teste da erro de strings,

<form action="cod.php" method="post">    
    <nav class="zz z_meio2 borda ">
  insira o código
<br>
      <input type=text name=CODNOME><br>
      <input type=submit value="OK">
    </nav>

Comment: @LuccasCerqueira não entendi... Deu errado?

Comment: @LuccasCerqueira coloque "aspas" no CODNOME. Assim: `<input type="text" name="CODNOME">`

Comment: @LuccasCerqueira poste o erro aqui nos comentários

Comment: @LuccasCerqueira ou então edite sua pergunta colocando no final dela todo o código. Assim eu consigo ver aonde está o erro exatamente.

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/teste_home/public_html/teste/imprimir3_novos.php on line 204"

Comment: @LuccasCerqueira poste todo esse arquivo "imprimir3_novos.php" NO FINAL DA SUA PERGUNTA. Para eu poder ver aonde está o erro.

Comment: @ja sei... O guilerme editou minha resposta errado. Vou editar la, copie e cole.

Comment: @LuccasCerqueira está lá! Alterei o código. Agora vai funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Para validar no PHP use a função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php), por exemplo:

```
<?php
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

Ela retorna `1` se for válido, `0` se for inválido ou `false` se ocorrer algum erro

O primeiro parâmetro da função é a regex e o segundo a string, no seu caso o valor enviado pelo usuário

Agora só precisa criar uma regex para validar, para testar expressões regulares recomendo esse [site](http://tools.lymas.com.br/regexp_br.php)

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi, tenho pouco conhecimento de php.

a premissa da minha lógica e apenas substituir o código dado pelo usuário por uma msg sem usar link ou pesquisa externa de preferencia sem acessar o banco de dados 

se o usuario digitar (001) vai aparecer a mensagem " A " 
se ele digitar (002) vai aparecer a mensagem " B "   

essa seria a logica que estou tentando usar.

acho que fica mas claro.

Comment: Agora deu pra entender com o título _"validar valor"_, imaginei que queria validar algo, nesse caso Andrei Coelho ja respondeu como pode fazer, recomendo `switch case`